# How to remain in python interactive interpreter after running program?

Tags: python, python-interactive

I am running python program from terminal

```
python -i abc.py <test.txt
```

but after completion of the program it does not remain in python.

what I want:

```
Output:
4 21
>>>
```

What is happening--

```
Output:
4 21
>>> >>> 
Downloads:~$
```

Usually if we give command
`python -i abc.py` it goes into python interactive mode after running the program.

Program(abc.py);

```
line=[]
f=int(raw_input())
i=0
while(i<f):
    m=raw_input()
    line.append(m)
    i+=1

for i in line:
    ind=i.find('$')
    temp=''
    for j in i[ind+1:]:
        t=ord(j)        
        if((t>=48)&(t<=57)):temp=temp+j
        elif(t!=32): break

    temp='$'+str(int(temp))
    print(temp)
```

test.txt

```
1
I want to buy Car for $10000
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the code has an `exit()` or anything inside it?

Comment: No, I have also included the program and test file for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You redirect the stdin, so when the file ends, the process exits.

What you is read from the file first, then from stdin:

```
(cat test.txt && cat) | python -i abc.py
```

Without any arguments, cat reads from stdin. So in this case, the python process first receives this output of `cat test.txt` and then the output of just `cat`, which is stdin.

Note that this does not behave exactly the same as using `python -i abc.py` without the redirect.

Comment: This does work, can you please explain  in detail why redirecting the stdin results in process exit. Why your method is working.